# Message: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Tags: sql, codeigniter

The following does not work and throws an exception.

**leaderboard_mode.php**

```
<?php

class Leaderboard_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_by_role()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query->("SELECT b. * FROM (SELECT a. *, @rank := @rank + 1 rank FROM (SELECT MAX(score) AS max_score, user_id FROM highscore WHERE game_mode="bungkata" GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC)a, (SELECT @rank := 0)r)b LIMIT 10");
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

> **An uncaught Exception was encountered**
>
> Type: ParseError
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\leaderboard\application\models\Leaderboard_model.php
>
> Line Number: 12
>
> Backtrace:
>
> > File: C:\wamp\www\leaderboard\application\controllers\Leaderboard.php
> >       Line: 9
> >       Function: model
> >
> > File: C:\wamp\www\leaderboard\index.php
> >       Line: 315
> >       Function: require_once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You just need to remove `->` from `query->`, like `$this->db->query()` Please see below updated code

```
public function get_by_role()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT b. * FROM (SELECT a. *, @rank := @rank + 1 rank FROM (SELECT MAX(score) AS max_score, user_id FROM highscore WHERE game_mode='bungkata' GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC)a, (SELECT @rank := 0)r)b LIMIT 10");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: please, look at my answer in this question

Answer (score 0):

change this query `$query = $this->db->query->` to  `$query = $this->db->query("your sql query")`

```
public function get_by_role()
{
    $query = $this->db->query->("SELECT b. * FROM (SELECT a. *, @rank := @rank + 1 rank FROM (SELECT MAX(score) AS max_score, user_id FROM highscore WHERE game_mode="bungkata" GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC)a, (SELECT @rank := 0)r)b LIMIT 10");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

leaderboard_model.php

```html
<?php
 
class Leaderboard_model extends CI_Model {

 function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_by_role()
   {
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT b. * FROM (SELECT a. *, @rank := @rank + 1 rank FROM (SELECT MAX(score) AS max_score, user_id FROM highscore WHERE game_mode=bungkata GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC)a, (SELECT @rank := 0)r)b LIMIT 10");
     return $query->result();
   }
}
```

controller : leaderboard.php

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Leaderboard extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model(array('Leaderboard_model'));
 }
 
 public function index(){
  $data['datarank'] = $this->leaderboard_model->get_by_role();
     $this->load->view('content_home', $data);
 }

}
```

my views: content_home.php

```html
<div id="main-description" class="col-md-6">
   <div class="heading text-center">
      <h1 class="text-white wow fadeInLeft"><strong>LEADERBOARD</strong></h1>
   </div>
   <div class="table-responsive text-white wow fadeInLeft">
   <table id="authusertable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
 <tr>
     <th>Peringkat</th>
     <th>Nama</th>
     <th>Point</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php
   $no = 0;
   foreach ($datarank as $row):
          $no++ ?>
 <tr>
      <td><?=$no?>
             <td><?=$row->user_id?></td>
             <td><?=$row->max_score?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VzNe.png)